# I am trying to convert a webkit command to moz o and ms

Tags: html, css, webkit, w3c

I am trying to find an alternative to the webkit command:

```
-webkit-text-fill-color
```

As this isnt yet supported in moz o and ms anyone know of another command which can do this or some sort of css hack i can use to get this effect?

Basically what im doing is making the text invisible, setting the background gradient invisible except where the text is and making that background show through to make a purely css gradiented text. anyone have any ideas? this is how i got it done with webkit:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e698c, #30576e);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

It works great in safari/chrome (duh :P ) but not in ie ff opera maxthon etc etc.

Comment: which software you use for writing html codes?

Comment: i use bluefish: http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html

Comment: ok I use Sublime Text 2 and just download one plugin in it which automatically add for moz,opera and ms if u want

Comment: pretty neat, but sadly wouldnt help in this situation. as the text-fill-color property is only supported by webkit and has no corresponding command in other browsers (yet) :/

Comment: in place of that use `color` and `webkit-text-fill-color` both are same and have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287552/difference-between-webkit-text-fill-color-and-color

Comment: Hmm let me try that. ill test it out tomorrow and get back to you. thanks for the link!

Comment: sorry to take so long getting back that did work in the end haha! thanks!

Comment: If you truly want a cross browser solution, the only way is to use SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved in the comments, so putting the comment in an answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

> in place of that use color and webkit-text-fill-color both are same and have a look to this [Difference between "-webkit-text-fill-color" and "color"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287552/difference-between-webkit-text-fill-color-and-color) – Arpit Srivastava Sep 14 '12 at 3:12

Also, all browsers except for IE support the webkit-text-fill-color even though it's not standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color#Browser_compatibility