# Is there a difference between using `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent` and `color: transparent`?

Tags: css

The behavior looks to be the same.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0052, #8e2b88);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

p.-webkit {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

p.color {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class="-webkit">-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent</p>
<p class="color">color: transparent</p>
```

(Or see [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bencergazda/pen/WKZMzE))

Browser support of `-webkit-background-clip: text` is weaker than of `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent`, so most probably we don't win better browser support, but does it change anything (like more/less optimal rendering)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287552/difference-between-webkit-text-fill-color-and-color ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color