# How can I style the first letter and apply this linear gradient animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, styled-components

I have some code using `background-position` and a `linear-gradient` in order to create a swiping right animation when you hover the text.

```css
div {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #8b73f6, #8b73f6 50%, #000 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.23, 1);
}

div:hover {
  background-position: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>Baz</div>
```

I want to combine this with the ability to color the first letter of my element so that the first letter is colored then on hover the rest is colored.

I used the  `::first-letter` pseudo-element and was able to change the color to purple that way:

```css
  div::first-letter {
    color: #8b73f6;
  }
```

```html
<div>Foo</div>
```

But, when I combine these, the linear-gradient always wins out and sits on top of my color. I could change the `background-position` on the div until it only shows color on the first letter, but then the solution only works for that specific letter because I'm not using a monospace font.

Here is my attempt at combining them:

```css
div {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #8b73f6, #8b73f6 50%, #000 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.23, 1);
}

div::first-letter {
  color: #8b73f6;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>Bar</div>
```

As an aside, I'm incorporating this using styled-components. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @yunzen, I just figured it out and posted the combination below as an answer. I needed to use `color` instead of `webkit-text-fill-color`. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that's why I put my solution as an answer @yunzen.

Comment: @yunzen Thanks for your feedback! I've added the original combination to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working as such! I just needed to stop using `-webkit-text-fill-color` and use normal `color`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287578/5007662) pointed me in the right direction.

```css
div {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #8b73f6, #8b73f6 50%, #000 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.23, 1);
}

div::first-letter {
  color: #8b73f6;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div>Foo</div>
```

Comment: hmm . so I didn't get the question well

Comment: @TemaniAfif Basically I wanted it to be purple on the first letter, and the rest black, then change to all purple on hover. I'm sorry I didn't make it very clear.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div:not(:hover)::first-letter {
    color: #8b73f6;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
}
```

```html
<div>Foo</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This isn't quite what I was looking for but I gave you an upvote because I think the idea of using `not` was clever here. I wasn't able to get it working with your example but I posted an answer with my solution. Welcome to Stack Overflow!