# Set gradient color on Angular mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I set gradient color on mat-icon Angular? I can set the color in css e.g., red, green, or any other solid colors like
`mat-icon {  color: red;  }`. But when trying to set to a gradient color like
`mat-icon {linear-gradient(to right, xxxxxx, #xxxxxx);}`
it has no effect. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

You could apply `linear-gradient(...)` to the background:

This will apply a background color and will not change the actual icon color:

```css
mat-icon {
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-hikkgt?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.css)

To apply a gradient color for the icon itself you could possibly do the following:

```css
mat-icon {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-vs3jwn?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.css)

`-webkit-text-fill-color` will do the trick for more info [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287578/4309639)